# Gif image in newsletter and the risk of spam

Tags: spam, gif

I am wondering if you find it risky to use a moving gif image in a newsletter. We have a mail list about 700k of people and the percentage of Outlook is still high. In a test we did the newsletter went in spam folder only in Outlook (ironic that gif files dont play in Outlook).

Some say you can't really predict if your newsletter is going to lie inside the spam folder of a user (you will be sure if you use javascript though :P) and it depends of many factors you can't predict (if the user opened recently a newsletter with a gif or the level of spam protect each user has).

The question is: Have you ever used an animated gif in your newsletter, do you think is risky to do so?

Thank you.

P.S. I know the question is more conversation-like but I couldn't avoid that.

**Feedback**: I finally used a gif image in our email newsletter and everything went very well. It just didnt play in outlook staying on the first frame but was acceptable. Android and iOs compatibility was great also.

Comment: Why would think it was risky?

Comment: Because in a test from experian our newsletter went to spam folder in Outlook, and the only thing it changed was the addition of gif image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SPAM filters are always changing and adapting and often it takes
>   multiple things “scoring” to reach a threshold that would then mark an
>   email as SPAM. That is to say that some SPAM filters might include the
>   animated GIF in part of their equation. For what it’s worth, it’s
>   become a bit of a trend and I’ve noticed many large brands and senders
>   adding small animations to enhance their content. You also might be
>   interested in a free guide we wrote that includes some interesting
>   info on how SPAM filters work.

http://blog.mailchimp.com/showing-vs-telling-with-gifs/

The mailchimp guys should know as they sound out 100's of thousands of emails daily, it's their business.

Comment: thanks for the link mate. seems closest to an answer. Will also provide feedback of our recent email with gif image on it cause I finally used one.